# How to fix ParserError: year 0 is out of range: 0000-00-00 with Python Pandas to_datetime method

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, string-to-datetime

I am trying to convert a column "travel_start" to a datetime object.

```
Dashboard["travel_start"] = pd.to_datetime(Dashboard["travel_start"])
```

But I get the following error:

```
ParserError: year 0 is out of range: 0000-00-00
```

When I tried to filter the column "travel_start" from the column in the dataframe. I see the dates below:

```
4922     0000-00-00
5592     0000-00-00
6647     0000-00-00
6796     0000-00-00
6941     0000-00-00
8223     0000-00-00
8391     0000-00-00
10137    0000-00-00
10197    0000-00-00
10744    0000-00-00
11128    0000-00-00
12304    0000-00-00
12511    0000-00-00
13307    0000-00-00
13681    0000-00-00
14381    0000-00-00
15160    0000-00-00
16330    0000-00-00
17734    0000-00-00
18148    0000-00-00
19389    0000-00-00
19643    0000-00-00
20372    0000-00-00
21412    0000-00-00
21757    0000-00-00
21879    0000-00-00
21978    0000-00-00
23216    0000-00-00
24375    0000-00-00
25660    0000-00-00
```

A count on this shows that they are 56 occurrence of this and I don't think it is smart to use the errors to cast it to NaT. What do you think I could change them to? or do?

Please your input is highly appreciated. thanks

Comment: can you post a few rows of your data, your error isn't reproducible. but it sounds like you need to specify the format, also `0000-00-00` is not a valid datetime object convert it to NaT with `pd.to_datetime(Dashboard["travel_start"],errors='coerce')`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I want to know if the date is correct or what is the correct way for this dates  0000-00-00

Comment: Unfortunately `0000-00-00` is not valid datetime.

Comment: What do you recommend? I coerce them to NaT?

Comment: @A.JT - yop, use `pd.to_datetime(Dashboard["travel_start"],errors='coerce')`

Comment: You can keep a tag on them with "9/9/9999"

Comment: What is the meaning for the value 0000-00-00? As a date it doesn’t exists, but someone did choose this non existing date for a reason

Comment: It is difficult to answer the question without having an understanding of what value **Dashboard["travel_start"]** has initially. 

I would recommend updating your question with this information, as to_datetime usally carries a unit conversion after it as a second parameter such as pd.to_datetime(1490195805, unit='s') without it, it would assume it would set a default which may not be what you are expecting to see, also display the dateframe, look for NaT values (Not a Time) as this will require a casting to take place first

Answer (score 0):

Pandas uses the pandas.Timestamp type to store date with time, instead pythons datetime.datetime.

The min/max values for TimeStamp are:

- `pd.Timestamp.min # return Timestamp('1677-09-21 00:12:43.145224193')`
- `pd.Timestamp.max # return Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')`

In your case we can clearly see that dates for those rows are simply missing / are unknown.

As @jezrael suggested use `pd.to_datetime(Dashboard["travel_start"],errors='coerce')` and treat all NaT as unknown.